edge collapse using garland-heckbert fails with unmet CGAL_precondition, what's going on?
I am running edge collapse on a mesh with 134 million faces. I am using the example code from here:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html#title20
"Example using Garland-Heckbert policies"
With this particular mesh, I now encounter the following error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Precondition_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: !get(vcm(), profile.v0()).isZero(0)
File: /nix/store/6x9gp50r6njnbb3whhn5d49v01ig016c-cgal-5.5.2/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Policies/Edge_collapse/internal/GarlandHeckbert_policy_base.h
Line: 227

This is the broader context of the precondition violation:
  // class GarlandHeckbert_cost_and_placement

  // Cost
  template <typename Profile>
  boost::optional<typename Profile::FT>
  operator()(const Profile& profile,
             const boost::optional<typename Profile::Point>& placement) const
  {
    typedef boost::optional<typename Profile::FT> Optional_FT;

    if(!placement)
      return boost::optional<typename Profile::FT>();

    CGAL_precondition(!get(vcm(), profile.v0()).isZero(0));
    CGAL_precondition(!get(vcm(), profile.v1()).isZero(0));

    const Mat_4 combined_matrix = combine_matrices(get(vcm(), profile.v0()),
                                                   get(vcm(), profile.v1()));
    const Col_4 pt = point_to_homogenous_column(*placement);
    const Optional_FT cost = (pt.transpose() * combined_matrix * pt)(0, 0);

    return cost;
  }

in file Surface_mesh_simplification/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Policies/Edge_collapse/internal/GarlandHeckbert_policy_base.h
This doesn't happen on every mesh, but already on a couple meshes.
I can't provide a sample mesh for easy reproduction yet (client data).
I prefer using Garland-Heckbert over Lindstrom-Turk because of this issue with Lindstrom-Turk.

The way I understand the failed precondition:

profile.v0() and profile.v1() are two vertices of some edge.
get makes a lookup in the "vertex cost map"/vcm, which probably gives the cost associated with the deletion of each vertex
this cost can't be exactly zero

Any idea how to go about debugging this? It would be interesting to know if this condition is linked to a certain characteristic in my input mesh.
There is no obvious weirdness in my input mesh by just looking at it.
